# query string in $resource url

Tags: angularjs

my service has to use a query string due to limitations on the server that runs classic ASP:

```
angular
  .module('myServices', ['ng', 'ngResource'])
  .factory('Item', ['$resource',
     function ($resource) {
         return $resource('/api/?p=item/:id');
     }]);
```

and I want to add extra query string parameters to it:

```
Item.query({test: 123}, on_success, on_error);
```

but the resulting url is

```
/api/?p=item?test=123
```

apparently there is a bug, but how to get around it?

EDIT: filed this at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1511

Comment: why do you use {test: 123} instead of {id: 123} ?

Comment: this is to test how parameters that are not specified in the resource work. anything that is not declared in the signature ends up in the query string.

Comment: Ok I misread your initial request but now I don't see why it's a bug ?

Comment: I think it is a bug because the resulting url contains two question marks. angularjs does not check if the route URL has a query string and just appends the second question mark.

Comment: Oups ok missed the first ?, I feel stupid.

Comment: It's not a bug, because by design you should not put query string in the path of the resource.

Comment: Same problem here... seems like angularjs bug (( Looking for workaround...

Answer (score 72):

You can use resource parameters. If you haven't specified placeholders in the path, they would  automatically be converted into query string params. Like that:

```
angular
    .module('myServices', ['ng', 'ngResource'])
    .factory('Item', [
         '$resource',
         function ($resource) {
             return $resource('/api');
     }]);

Item.query({p: 'item/1'});
```

This would result in a request to `/api?p=item/1`.

P.S.

I suppose you already know that, but you don't like it. But I still think this is the correct way in your case. Considering the bad API design you are dealing with that back-end you could wrap the AngularJS resources with another service which does this for you.

Comment: Good example. I wish this had been in the Angular tutorial. All parameters are hardcoded in their $resource examples.

Comment: I don't see how this question actually answered the OP question. The OP already knew about dynamically adding a query param, and using a Factory. The information itself might be very useful, but I don't see why it was actually provided over and above what the OP already wrote. Did I miss something in the proposed answer that added extra value?

Comment: @arcseldon The OP had a problem with two `?` question mark characters in the URLs. This fixes the problem. It also points out that params which are not defined as placeholders in the path go in the query string.

Comment: @ Haralan Dobre - Thank you for your clarification! Ok, I wish the example provided above had indeed then been written with two query params appended and a one line saying - " and the result is a url with query string that looks like "/api/?p=item&test=123" which is precisely what the OP was asking about. In either case, thank you again for this clarification. I was unsure whether the proposed answer worked, and the OP has not acknowledged it as the answer either which doubled the confusion.

Comment: @arcseldon I did not mark this response as an answer because it did not help me. I already know what this response proposes and my question actually uses this already.

Comment: @akonsu - Agreed. That was my point above so thank you for confirming. Still, good to know that your question, and Haralan's suggested answer have both helped people.

Answer (score 0):

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
api.api_name.query({
    'param':param_value
},
    function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    },
    function(response) {
        deferred.reject(response);
    }
);
//
angular
    .module('module_name')
    .factory('api',function($resource){
        var api_var={};
        api_var.api_name = $resource('url?param_key=:param', {
            param: '@param'
        }, {
            'query': {
                method: 'get'
            }
        });
        return api_var;
    });
```