# HTTP POST with URL query parameters in Angular

Tags: angularjs, http, url, parameters

I am trying to send POST request which contains url param, url query params and body.

My resource looks like this:

```
return $resource(myService.getResourceUrl('/users/:username/password'), {}, {
    resetPassword: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {passwordResetToken: '@passwordResetToken'}
    }
});
```

Resource is used in service:

```
 resetPassword: function(username, password, config){
        return ru.handleErrors(passwordManagerResource.save({username: username}, password, config).$promise);
    }
```

And finally service is called in the main controller:

```
var config = {passwordResetToken: '39af3539-12f8-4285-8a96-526a25c0fa00'};

var password = {password: 'Aaaaaaaa01'};

userManagementService.resetPassword("test_user", password, config).then(function(res){
        console.log("helllloooo_again");
}
```

However query parameters are not added to the url. Generated URL has following structure:

http://localhost:8080/ghostwriter/users/test_user/password

instead of
http://localhost:8080/ghostwriter/users/test_user/password?passwordResetToken=39af3539-12f8-4285-8a96-526a25c0fa00

Comment: I'm removing my answer, maybe someone else will be able to help.

Comment: refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147435/query-string-in-resource-url/43819322#43819322