# How to pass query string with resources in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is there is any way to pass query string with Angularjs resources. I have seen some example which explain how to do it but my scenario is different. I want to pass in my custom metohd.

Example I have seen is like [query string in $resource url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147435/query-string-in-resource-url)

```
Item.query({p: 'item/1'});
```

**app.js**

```
$resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
```

**apiservice.js**

```
 return $resource(Config.getURL() + '/api/:request/', {
        request: '@request'
    },
    {

      getmylocation:{
        method:'GET',
        params:{
          request:'getmylocation'
        }
      },     

      setItemDetails: {
        method: 'POST',
        params:{
          request:'showlist'
        }
      },

    });
```

**controller**

```
apiService.getmylocation()
```

Url should look like : http://www.name.com/api/getmylocation?query=newlocation

Comment: Could you please clarify what you got and what result this gives and what result you want. It's a bit hard to get this out of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it is now working in your particular case, but will be like this only -:

```
apiService.getmylocation({query:'newlocation'}).$promise.then(function(){
}, function(error){
})
```

I created a scenario and tested  it...its working fine...same url is getting generated...:)

Answer (score 0):

I made a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sexetusawi/edit?js,console) using the JSONPlaceholder API

From the [$resource Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> HTTP GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])`

I hope this is useful, feel free to modify this example to your needs.